# Loop down column until blank cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

The following formula works well **if** I define each cell (over and over), but I need a loop that will run down column A & B for hundreds of rows.
I have tried and just cannot seem to be able to write a loop that runs and stops when it hits an empty cell at the bottom.
This needs to be able to run on multiple spreadsheets with different tab names.

Example of what works now:  [ I want to have one formula that loops ]
I currently have this written out for 100 lines, since I cannot get a loop to work.  :-(

```
Sub Hidelines()

If Range("A1").Value = "No" Then
    Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B1").Value = "NEVER" Then
    Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

If Range("A2").Value = "No" Then
    Rows("2:2").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B2").Value = "NEVER" Then
    Rows("2:2").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

If Range("A3").Value = "No" Then
Range("E3").Select
    Rows("3:3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B3").Value = "NEVER" Then
    Rows("3:3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub HideRows()
Dim RowCount: RowCount = 1   ' Row you wish to start from
Dim ColIndex: ColIndex = 1   ' Column to look within (A = 1) - Never will be in ColIndex + 1

Do
    If (LCase(Cells(RowCount, ColIndex).Value) = "no") Then
        Cells(RowCount, ColIndex).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf (LCase(Cells(RowCount, ColIndex + 1).Value) = "never") Then
        Cells(RowCount, ColIndex).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(RowCount, ColIndex).Value)

End Sub
```

This will keep going down each row until it hits an empty cell in column `ColIndex`. It will case insensitively look at the same column for `No` or the column one to the right of it for `Never`, and hide the row if so.

Comment: **Thank you!!** - your responses have helped me before...  Ed